# Differentiating Adblock Disabled from Whitelist

Tags: javascript, web, whitelist, adblock

Simple question here: I know there are lots of ways to detect a user is using adblock on the web using Javascript but I was wondering if there's a way to specifically detect when a user has whitelisted a website (as opposed to simply disable adblocking). I assume this varies based on the blocker but for the sake of simplicity lets just say AdBlock Plus.

Currently I can easily detect adblocking by simply seeing if my ads object has successfully loaded from an external script. I then store this boolean in `localStorage` so upon subsequent user visits I can detect if there's been a change in the user's adblocking. If so I thank them for disabling/whitelisting and update the `localStorage`. However it might be required to handle these two actions separately.

Any and all help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How about BlockAdBlock on github that can detect most adblock forms

Comment: As stated in my original question, I can detect adblock easily as is. I'm displaying a message asking users to whitelist the site if detect. So I'd like to be able to specifically thank users who permanently whitelist the site as opposed just temporarily disable their adblock. To do so I need to differentiate between adblock disabled and whitelisted.

Comment: As a follow up, there is no way to detect the difference between ad block off and whitelist. I believe this would only be possible if the browser and or ad blocker proactively messaged the DOM to let it know what ad state it was in (which they obviously do not do and I doubt they ever will).